# How can I suppress the output of file errors when using tqdm?

Tags: python, exception, io, tqdm

I am loading a bunch of files and want to show a corresponding progress bar using tqdm.

```
for file_path in tqdm(file_paths, position=0, desc='files loaded'):
    if is_binary(file_path):
        continue

    try:    
        with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf8', errors='ignore') as input_file:
            file_content = input_file.read()
                    
            processing_queue.put(file_content)
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        main_logger.error(f'Encountered exception while opening {file_path}: {e}')
```

Even though I am handling files that could not be found with an exception, I still get error messages printed to the console which interfere with the output of tqdm:

```
files loaded:  99%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████▎ | 257398/260429 [6:17:16<07:16,  6.95it/s]
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\\\server\\path\\to\\file'██████                                                                                   | 112570/260429 [6:17:11<7:05:21,  5.79it/s] 
files loaded: 100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 260429/260429 [6:21:29<00:00, 11.38it/s]
```

Why are these messages still printed to the console and what can be done to supress them?

Comment: Your `main_logger` has StreamHandler, use only FileHandler when don't want to print in the console.

Comment: @ZavenZareyan main_logger is using a FileHandler already, the problem is that the error message is still printed to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed it by opening the file in a seperate try/except block first!

```
for file_path in tqdm(file_paths, position=0, desc='files loaded'):
    try:
        open(file_path).close()
    except EnvironmentError as e:
        main_logger.error(f'Encountered exception while opening {file_path}: {e}')
        continue


    if is_binary(file_path):
        continue

        
    with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf8', errors='ignore') as input_file:
        file_content = input_file.read()
                    
        processing_queue.put(file_content)
```